# Jetpack Compose: No background in OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have two layers in my Compose layout: One for the actual content and the one above is a Box-wrapped `OutlinedTextField` for search queries.

Here's the sample code:

```
// Placeholder for layout content
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.lorem_ipsum),
        color = Color.Gray
    )
}

// Overlaying Box with OutlinedTextField
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp, top = 64.dp)
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = viewModel.query.value,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.updateQuery(it) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .navigationBarsWithImePadding(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters,
            autoCorrect = false,
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.None
        ),
        shape = CircleShape,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.White
        ),
        placeholder = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.search_input_placeholder)) },
        maxLines = 1,
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

Even though I'm setting

```
colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.White
    )
```

in the `OutlinedTextField`, the background stays transparent as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Adding a background color on the `OutlinedTextField's` modifier is giving the whole row a rectangled background, which is also not the desired result.

The `OutlinedTextField` with it's `CircleShape` should only have a background inside of the shape. How can I achieve that?

I'm using Jetpack Compose version 1.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

Unfortunately, in version 1.0.4, `OutlinedTextField` ignores the `backgroundColor` even if you specify it, so you can remove the `colors` parameter.

Support for it will be added in 1.1.0:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1741240
It's already present in 1.1.0-alpha06 so you can play with it if you want. Your original code should produce desired outcome on that version.

### Solution

To achieve what you want (before 1.1.0 is released) you can simply add a background modifier with the same shape:

```
.background(Color.White, CircleShape)
```

Since the order of modifiers is important, you should add it after you apply all the paddings (`navigationBarsWithImePadding` in your case). Like that:

```
modifier = Modifier
  .fillMaxWidth()
  .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
  .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
  .background(Color.White, CircleShape),
```

**Note**: Also be aware that you cannot use the `label` parameter with this approach, because the `TextField` with `label` will be higher than just the outline shape and these two shaped wouldn't match in size anymore.

### Result

Entire code:

```
// Placeholder for layout content
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.lorem_ipsum),
        color = Color.Gray
    )
}

// Overlaying Box with OutlinedTextField
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp, top = 64.dp)
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = viewModel.query.value,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.updateQuery(it) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
            .background(Color.White, CircleShape),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters,
            autoCorrect = false,
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.None
        ),
        shape = CircleShape,
        placeholder = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.search_input_placeholder)) },
        maxLines = 1,
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

How the final result looks like:

[image]

Comment: good catch, with compose version `1.1.0-alpha06` it's working without any code change